# NSDICTIONARY with multiple keys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a NSDICTIONARY :

```
(
    {
      Edad = 11;
      Genero = M;
      IdArea = 1;
      IdEmpleado = 11;
      Nombre = Manuel;
    },
    {
      Edad = 30;
      Genero = M;
      IdArea = 2;
      IdEmpleado = 2;
      Nombre = Luis;
    }

)
```

How I can do to separate the data in quotes?, To find the values ​​for keys.

```
       {
          Edad = 11;
          Genero = M;
          IdArea = 1;
          IdEmpleado = 11;
          Nombre = Manuel;
        }

         objectforkey @"genero" = M
```

thanks for the help

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Can you rephrase?

Comment: is a NSDICTIONARY that contains data of several people with the same values ​​as you see, separated in quotes.

So I need to obtain separate values ​​for each key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the data structure you posted :-

It is array which contains number of dictionaries.

Now for extracting  values for particular key you need to do is:-

Suppose `DataArray` is the array which holds your data.
Now

```
for (int i=0; i<[self.DataArray count]; i++) 
{

NSDictionary *dict=[self.DataArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSString *genreString=[dict objectForKey:@"genero"];
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, if I worked.
JSON converted the NSArray, then each array in order to use their NSDICIONARY KEY